# Finding pattern in 2d array with numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix

I have an array of 1s and zeros called a.
for example:

```
a= 
[[0,0,1,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,1]]
```

and a kernel (k):

```
k =
[[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]]
```

I want to find all instances of k inside a.
I want the result of the convolution to be:

```
conv(a,k) = 
    [[0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Is there a built in function?

I know it can be done with for-loops, but this is WAY too slow for large arrays.
Thx

Comment: If you are fine with scipy, it has a convolve method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to apply the convolution with numpy.fft

Code from: https://laurentperrinet.github.io/sciblog/posts/2017-09-20-the-fastest-2d-convolution-in-the-world.html#using-directly-numpy

```
from numpy.fft  import fft2, ifft2
def np_fftconvolve(A, B):
    return np.real(ifft2(fft2(A)*fft2(B, s=A.shape)))
```